# Fetching record using rid and limit

Tags: orientdb

I have 500 000 records in class.

I want to fetch 2 000 records and send for processing.

Query :

```
SELECT FROM class WHERE @rid > "#-1:-1" ORDER BY @rid ASC LIMIT 2000
```

> fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an
>   index or change the query to use an existent index [OProfiler]

How to avoid this warning ?

I have tried with between operator as well . I am getting the same warning.

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: I tried your query and I have no problems, no warning.

Comment: thank you , After removing Quotes in rid .the warning has removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried `SELECT FROM class WHERE @rid > "#-1:-1" ORDER BY @rid ASC LIMIT 2000` with OrientDb 2.0.13 and I haven't any warning. I get your exception if I try for example with limit 51000.

> Query 'SELECT FROM Persona WHERE @rid > "#-1:-1" ORDER BY @rid ASC
>   LIMIT 51000' fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the
>   execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent
>   index [OProfiler].

You shouldn't have this exception if you use limit = 2000.

Looking at the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Pagination.html#use-the-rid-limit and trying with "#-1:-1" and #-1:-1, the query works for me in both cases.